# (Nicer) user leagues per tag

Tags: feature-request, reputation-leagues

The thing is, I think I'm doing OK. I haven't been on SO for that long, but I put in the time, I get the votes and answers and I am currently on [#7 in the user league](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow/2010-11-08/446261?sort=reputationchange#446261). But the thing is, no matter how hard I try, I won't beat [Nick Craver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13249/nick-craver). [He has the girl](http://www.ncraver.com/Wedding/index.html), [he has the score](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13249?tab=reputationhistory) and I'm not going to get his face off of the user league.

[image: Nick Craver Nick Craver Nick Craver Nick Craver]

But even though he does very well, he gets most his points answering jQuery questions and I'm a C# guy.

I envision user leagues based on tags. I know, tags can be changed and it may not be trivial to define how someone scored on a tag. But if you'd for instance include a user in a tag league when 50% of his answers are to questions with a specific tag, it could very well be representative.

And at last, I'll have a chance again.

**EDIT:**
OK, it's official, I'm blind. @Pekka answered that this already exists. However, is there a chance that this could look as nice as the normal user league, including the week, quarter and year score?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mean like [these](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/topusers)? :)

Comment: Still, this does not nearly look as nice as the main user league. No chance the format could change to the normal user leagues, with weeks and quarters and such?

Comment: @Pieter I don't know, but it may well be possible - we'll see what people say